# How to prevent node.js from crashing when opening too many files at once?

Tags: node.js

When scanning a directory tree with node.js, as we utilise asynchronous callbacks with a large directory it is easy to instantly queue up more than a 1000 fs operations at once which often causes the node.js process to crash or simply for the fs operations to fail with a "EM too many open files" error.

Has anyone figured out an elegant way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for the years:

1. I coded a https://npmjs.com/package/safefs package based on this answer
2. Isaac coded a https://npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs package
3. Safefs now uses the graceful-fs package
4. The same problem exists for processes, so I created the https://npmjs.com/package/safeps package which solves this issue among many others

—

Not sure if this is the best way to solve this issue, but what I've effectively done is wrapped all the asynchronous fs functions with a wrapper that checks whether or not the we have more than the allowed amount of files open (arbitrarily set to a reasonable 100). If there is more than that many files open at the time of the call, the call will idle and check again after a delay to see if there is now an opening. The code for this logic can be found here: https://github.com/balupton/bal-util/blob/master/src/lib/paths.coffee#L7-45

In terms of implementing it, you just need to change `require('fs').readFile` or whatever call you are using to `require('bal-util').readFile` and install the [bal-util](https://github.com/balupton/bal-util) dependency (`npm install bal-util`) which is simple enough.

Hope this helps. If there is a more robust way of doing this, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest pattern I've used involved using the `async` module (https://github.com/caolan/async) with a queue.  You can set the maximum number of concurrent items in the queue.

```
var queue = async.queue(do_thing, 500);
queue.drain = function() {
    console.log("Done with entries");
};

queue.push(workitem);
```